# Match multiple yields in any order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, iterator, yield

I want to test an iterator using rspec. It seems to me that the only possible yield matcher is `yield_successive_args` (according to https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/built-in-matchers/yield-matchers). The other matchers are used only for single yielding.

But `yield_successive_args` fails if the yielding is in other order than specified.

Is there any method or nice workaround for testing iterator that yields in **any** order?

Something like the following:

```
expect { |b| array.each(&b) }.to yield_multiple_args_in_any_order(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: I added a feature request, feel free to suggest a better name than `yield_multiple_args`: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/595

Comment: can you provide the iterator code here as well?

Comment: I am looking for a general solution for any iterator, the only thing that matters is that it yields all params in any order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the matcher I came up for this problem, it's fairly simple, and should work with a good degree of efficiency.

```
require 'set'

RSpec::Matchers.define :yield_in_any_order do |*values|
  expected_yields = Set[*values]
  actual_yields = Set[]

  match do |blk|
    blk[->(x){ actual_yields << x }]    # ***
    expected_yields == actual_yields    # ***
  end

  failure_message do |actual|
    "expected to receive #{surface_descriptions_in expected_yields} "\
    "but #{surface_descriptions_in actual_yields} were yielded."
  end

  failure_message_when_negated do |actual|
    "expected not to have all of "\
    "#{surface_descriptions_in expected_yields} yielded."
  end

  def supports_block_expectations?
    true
  end
end
```

I've highlighted the lines containing most of the important logic with `# ***`. It's a pretty straightforward implementation.

### Usage

Just put it in a file, under `spec/support/matchers/`, and make sure you require it from the specs that need it. Most of the time, people just add a line like this:

```
Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/support/**/*.rb"].each {|f| require f}
```

to their `spec_helper.rb` but if you have a lot of support files, and they aren't all needed everywhere, this can get a bit much, so you may want to only include it where it is used.

Then, in the specs themselves, the usage is like that of any other yielding matcher:

```
class Iterator
  def custom_iterator
    (1..10).to_a.shuffle.each { |x| yield x }
  end
end

describe "Matcher" do
  it "works" do
    iter = Iterator.new
    expect { |b| iter.custom_iterator(&b) }.to yield_in_any_order(*(1..10))
  end
end
```

Comment: For reference, there is an issue on github: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/pull/595 and pull request: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/pull/596. Maybe when there is more demand, it will make it's way to the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in plain Ruby using a set intersection of arrays:

```
array1 = [3, 2, 4]
array2 = [4, 3, 2]
expect(array1).to eq (array1 & array2)

# for an enumerator:
enumerator = array1.each
expect(enumerator.to_a).to eq (enumerator.to_a & array2)
```

The intersection (`&`) will return items that are present in both collections, keeping the order of the first argument.

Comment: What about `array1 = [3, 2, 4]; array2 = [4, 3, 2, 1]` ? I suggest here the `match_array` matcher would be more fit when comparing arrays.

Comment: This can lead to a quazi-correct answer when there is an iterator with method `each` and you use `iterator.to_enum.to_a` with a `match_array` matcher. But the question was about yielding of any iterator method, not providing correct `to_enum` method.